# How to throw an observable error manually?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on an Angular app in which I am making a rest call through HTTP as below:

```
login(email, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = `identity=${email}&password=${password}`;
    return this.http.post(`${this._configService.getBaseUrl()}/login`, body, options)
    .map((res: any) => {
        let response: any = JSON.parse(res._body);
        if (response.success == 0) {
          Observable.throw(response);  // not working
        } else if (response.success == 1) {
          console.log('success');
          localStorage.setItem('auth_token', 'authenticated');
          this.loggedIn = true;
          return response;
        }
    });
}
```

Basically I want my component to get response & error in my subscribe call, i.e.

```
this._authenticateService.login(this.loginObj['identity'],this.loginObj['password']).subscribe(
  (success)=>{      
    this.credentialsError=null;  
    this.loginObj={};  
    this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);    
  },
  (error)=>{
    console.log(error);        
    this.credentialsError=error;     
  }
);
```

but my API always returns success as it is defined that way.

How can I throw an error message if `response.success == 0`,  so that it will be accessed inside error argument of my subscribe callback?

Comment: what is the status code you are getting, i mean it can be else then 0?

Comment: @MrJSingh the guy who designed the API only returned success as 0 or 1 to validate the response.so I my operation was successfull,it will return success =1 or it will return success=0 .now I want to throw error if success is 0.is that possible?

Comment: Let me try on my app, technically it should be possible.

Comment: try this return Observable.throw(response);

Comment: You can try doing this: it´s a similar case https://stackoverflow.com/a/55286461/8342681

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
if (response.success == 0) {
   throw Observable.throw(response);  
 }
```

**Edit for *rxjs 6*:**

```
if (response.success == 0) {
   throw throwError(response);  
 }
```

Comment: I am getting  it in success callback even after not using this

Comment: i don't understand, what do you mean even when not using it? could you explain it to me? i tested it as you have the case and Observable will throw error only if success is 0.

Comment: I mean if my response is returning anything , be it error or success, it will always return it into success callback.I want error to be thrown in error callback..

Comment: i.e. even if I dont use Observable.throw , I can access error in success callback

Comment: ok then we need to change code a little bit. i will come back to you in short!

Comment: here it is the trick throw Observable.throw(response) now your response will be injected into error object. you can log and see it.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: This method is deprecated, see answer below (using throwError from 'rxjs')

Comment: This will return an Observable in the error callback which isn't good code design. Instead just throw your own error object `throw { message: 'Bad response', value: response}`

Answer (score 123):

**rxjs 6**

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

if (response.success == 0) {
  return throwError(response);  
}
```

**rxjs 5**

```
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

if (response.success == 0) {
  return new ErrorObservable(response);  
}
```

What you return with `ErrorObservable` is up to you

Comment: The accepted answer solution is deprecated in rxjs6. Thank you, your one works :)

Comment: This is the way to go when used within an operator that is expected to return an Observable like `switchMap` or `mergeMap`. When used within `map` you will end up with a nested Observable (you will get an Observable in the success callback of your Observable) which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 14):

with rxjs 6

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
throwError('hello');
```

Comment: Care to explain why is that better than the native part of the language i.e. the `throw` keyword?

Comment: @Endrju it's completely different. return throwError will return observable that you can then handle with catchError or inside subsribe. if you throw new Error('') this will bubble up and won't be handled inside observables...

Comment: Just calling `throwError` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 13):

rxjs 7

```
throwError(() => new Error(response))
```

more info
https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/breaking-changes#throwerror

Answer (score 12):

**rxjs 5**

Either

```
throw response;
```

or

```
throw Observable.throw(response);
```

Comment: for the second one it will be:
`throw Observable.throw(response)`

Comment: +1 for the simple `throw response`. Everything else, e.g. returning an ErrorObservable or throwing an ErrorObservable inside `map` isn't ideal as you will end up with a nested Observable.

Comment: is the second one deprecated?

Comment: @Farhad yes it's deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512534/5493813 for the correct answer

Answer (score 8):

Here is the official example (that emits number 7 and then error 'oops!'):

```
import { throwError, concat, of } from 'rxjs';

const result = concat(of(7), throwError(new Error('oops!')));
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x), e => console.error(e));
```

From:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError

Answer (score 0):

Use the catch operator

```
this.calcSub = this.http.post(this.constants.userUrl + "UpdateCalculation", body, { headers: headers })
   .map((response: Response) => {
      var result = <DataResponseObject>response.json();
         return result;
   })
   .catch(this.handleError)
   .subscribe(
      dro => this.dro = dro,
      () => this.completeAddCalculation()
   );
```

And handle the error like this:

```
private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
}
```

Comment: my api never calls catch block. thats the issue I am having. In my response I want to check for certain condition and then  throw the error or call the catch block.

Comment: I've gotten this error with private handleError(error: Response)

__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.a.throw is not a function
    at CatchSubscriber.selector

Comment: @NamLe you have to import throw in order to use it. `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';`

Answer (score 0):

Most of my issues were related to the imports, so here's the code that worked for me...

```
import {_throw} from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
login(email, password) {
...
    return this.http.post(`${this._configService.getBaseUrl()}/login`, body, options)
    .map((res: any) => {
...
        if (response.success == 0) {
           _throw(response);  
        } else if (response.success == 1) {
...
        }
    });
}
```

This will be the solution if you are facing errors like...

> ERROR TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable**.Observable.throw is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you're throwing an error you'll be doing so at the exact moment the problem occurred and you want to raise it immediately, but this may not always be the case.

For instance there is the `timeoutWith()` operator, which is perhaps one of the most likely reasons you'll need to do this.

```
results$ = server.getResults().pipe(timeoutWith(10000, ....) )
```

This takes an 'error factory', which is a function.

```
 errorFactory = () => 'Your error occurred at exactly ' + new Date()
```

eg.

```
results$ = server.searchCustomers(searchCriteria).pipe(timeoutWith(10000, 
              () => 'Sorry took too long for search ' + JSON.stringify(searchCriteria)) )
```

Note that when using `timeoutWith` you'll never get the actual server response back - so if the server gave a specific error you'd never see it. This above example can be very useful in debugging, but be sure not to display the error to the end user if you use the above example.

AN error factory is helpful because it doesn't evaluate the code until the actual error occurs. So you can put 'expensive' or debugging operations inside that will get executed when the error is actually finally needed.

If you need to use a 'factory' to create your error somewhere other than in timeout you can use the following.

```
 EMPTY.pipe(throwIfEmpty(errorFactory))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use catchError(error) => console.log(error) inside a pipe

Answer (score 0):

In rxjs 8 I needed to do:

```
.pipe(
  map(response => {
    if (!response.success) throw throwError(() => response);
    return response;
  }
)
```

I think the only breaking change is that now `throwError` requires a callback and not an object