# Manually throw error ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am communicating with a webservice and the return can be negative or porisitvo and will fall into the success of the call, but if the return is negative I need to manually throw an exception

```
 .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => {
    let returno = JSON.parse(res.d);  
    if (returno.status == 'success') {
      this._loggedIn(returno);
    } else {
      throw returno;
    }
  }, err => {
    console.error('ERROR', err);
  });
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511948/how-to-throw-observable-error-manually-in-angular2

Comment: that doesnt work too

Comment: What did not work ? Please elaborate ..

Answer (score 1):

You can throw exceptions in JS by just passing objects to `throw`. So `throw err` in your case.

Comment: dont work like that! I need to hit this line _console.error('ERROR', err);_

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'll want all of your subscribers to handle the error in the same way? Therefore, you can handle the error at the Observable level, not the Subscriber level.

Thus, you can do something like the following:

```
public tryLogin(url: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json().d)
    .map(res => {
      if (res.status !== 'success') {
        Observable.throw(res);
      }

      return res;
    });
}
```

Then you can call this code in the following fashion:

```
this.tryLogin('mydata')
  .subscribe(
    data => this._loggedIn(data),
    err => console.log(err);
  )
```

The great thing with this approach is, if you don't want your subscribers to know what's gone on, you can abstract that and either authenticate them in the `next` callback, or handle the event of a failure in the `error` callback.