# Returning observable via pipe Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I want to send rejected observable in http client success based on some condition , but subscribing to observable is always resulting in a success only

```
return this.http.post(final_url, data, headers)
                .pipe(map((data) => throwError(data)), 
                .catchError((data) =>  this.errorCallback(data, showError)
                ))
```

Component, where I am catching response, is here:

```
this.service.authenticate(this.user).subscribe(response => {
     console.log("success registered", response); 
    }, error => {
      console.log("Error registered");
    });
```

Even I am returning throwError observable, success is registered in my subscribing component.

Any mistake i am doing ??

Comment: what do you mean by error? what is returning on server side error occured?

Comment: Return from server side is 200 , so it will go in map part of pipe , there i am returning a error observable..
When i am subscribing that error observable , it should be in error part of subscription instead its going in success part

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511948/how-to-throw-observable-error-manually-in-angular2

Comment: throw( new Error( "custom error" ) ); or throwError(new Error('custom error!'));

Comment: If it is 200 angular don't know about the error? it is a success response.

Comment: can you show the function?

Comment: A question I'd like to ask you is, why you're doing that in the first place? If your intent is to play around with the library to completely understand it, I think you might want to also have a look at the source code for [`throwError`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/throwError.ts)

Comment: Actually there is more to a code i am showing , there is logic i created a wrapper for all http services which do extra stuff , code i showed is bare minimum of what problem actuallly is in the library

Comment: I guess problem is solved , inside the pipe instead of returning throwError i have to throw the error actually.
thanks all