# Conditionally fire mergeMap, if false throw error

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
    .pipe(
        map(params => {
            return params.get('ID'))
        }),
        mergeMap(val => {
            if(val)
                return this.GetData(val)
                .pipe(
                    map((res:any)=>{
                    return JSON.parse(res.data);
                    })
                );
            else
                throwError(new Error('ID is missing'));
        }),
    ).subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x)
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
```

What I am trying to do is fetch the ID querystring, if it exists then fires a get request else throw an error. I could do this inside the subscribe(), however doing that would I would have to nest it(subscribe inside a subscribe).
However when I try to throw an error I am getting this error: ***TypeError: "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."***

Comment: Possibly  duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511948/how-to-throw-observable-error-manually-in-angular2).

Comment: thanks, I fixed it......i had to `return throwError(new Error('ID is missing'));`